# Transferring values in a vector into a structure in c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have a text file that contains values like

```
[1, 2]-3-Big_City
[1, 3]-3-Big_City
[2, 1]-3-Big_City
[2, 2]-3-Big_City
[2, 3]-3-Big_City
[2, 7]-2-Mid_City
[2, 8]-2-Mid_City
[3, 1]-3-Big_City
[3, 2]-3-Big_City
[3, 3]-3-Big_City
[3, 7]-2-Mid_City
[3, 8]-2-Mid_City
[7, 7]-1-Small_City
```

I managed to separate them into separate lines using a string tokenizer I found.

```
std::vector<std::string> tokenizeString(std::string input, std::string delimiter)
{
    size_t pos = 0;
    std::string token;
    std::vector<std::string> result;

    while ((pos = input.find(delimiter)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        token = input.substr(0, pos);
        result.push_back(token);
        input.erase(0, pos + delimiter.length());
    }

    result.push_back(input);

    return (result);
}
```

And this is the function where I called the string tokenizer

```
    filename = lineArray[2];
    std::fstream inputFile(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::in);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string line;
    cityLoc city;

    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        std::vector<std::string> tokenStringVector = tokenizeString(line, "-");

        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < tokenStringVector.size(); i++)
            std::cout << tokenStringVector[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The problem is that I'm not allowed to use vectors to store the value of `tokenStringVector`, and I can't figure out how to transfer the value of a vector into the struct `city`. All I could find was storing a vector in a struct which is not what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: Here's the structure of cityLoc, I don't really know how to store the coords so I decided to just go with a `std::string` since I figured I could just remove the brackets and comma afterwards.

```
struct cityLoc {
    std::string cityCoords;
    int cityId;
    std::string cityName;
};
```

Comment: What is the reason for not using vector? Is this some "we-use-c++-but-teach-c-instead" course?

Comment: You can use `std::list`, when you are not allowed to use `std::vector`, but your teacher will not be happy when you bend the rules like that.

Comment: @OlafDietsche It's one of the assignment requirements. We're allowed to use vectors for stuff like string tokenisation but the values must be stored in an array or a structure.

Comment: @mch How do I go about storing the std::vector<std::string> tokenStringVector into a list? I think lists are allowed.

Comment: Using `std::list` is more or less the same, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back

Comment: @OlafDietsche Oh so instead of storing it in a struct I should store it in a list instead? Thanks for the link

Comment: If you are allowed to use a list, this is one solution. If you have always three tokens, you could also use a `struct city` with three elements, maybe like `{ range, size, name }`

Comment: *I can't figure out how to transfer the value of a vector into the struct city*. Well as you do not say anything about `city` I cannot either... What is the expected result?

Comment: Oh sorry I'll edit the question to add my declaration of struct city in too

Comment: @OlafDietsche After reading through it it would seem list is out too as it's kinda similar to a vector and I don't think it's allowed too

Comment: Rather than splitting `line` into a variable number of strings, you need to split it into three specific things, a `std::string`(or perhaps a `Coords` type you also need to define), an `int` and a `std::string`

Comment: I.e. you want a function like `cityLoc fromString(std::string line) { cityLoc result; /* somehow populate result.coords, result.id, result.name */ return result; }`

Comment: @Caleth How do I do that? Do I use `std::string::substr()` to do that? And will it track the newlines or not because I have quite a few of those in my file?

Comment: What have you been taught about converting text to numbers?

Comment: @Caleth I just used `std::stoi()` when I was asked to do that

Answer (score 0):

Since each line in your input file has fixed number of tokens ( here 3). Instead of using vector you can use an array of strings. And done.  You can write tokenizer function like

```
void tokenizeString(std::string input, std::string delimiter, string tokenArray[])
{
    // Tokenize the string and put the tokens in tokenArray

}
```

And you can call this functions as below(just edit in your code)

```
 filename = lineArray[2];
    std::fstream inputFile(filename.c_str(), std::fstream::in);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::string line;
    int count = 0;
    cityLoc city;
    string tokenArray[5]; // Any length bigger than 3 would work because of the input file structure
    while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        count++;
        tokenizeString(line, "-", tokenArray);

        std::cout << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            std::cout << tokenArray[i] << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However the code doesn't print out anything. My input file structure is like that because I had to get the file name from another file, and I stored it in a array, so I had to use an array to get the file name.

Answer (score 0):

A line looks like

> [1, 2]-3-Big_City

and is split into three elements, using `-` as separator

- [1, 2]
- 3
- Big_City

This would map to the struct like

- coords: [1, 2]
- id: 3
- name: Big_City

The tokenizer could then be

```
cityLoc tokenizeString(const std::string &input, const std::string &delimiter)
{
    size_t pos, start;
    std::string token;
    cityLoc result;

    pos = input.find(delimiter);
    result.cityCoords = input.substr(0, pos);

    start = pos + delimiter.size();
    pos = input.find(delimiter, start);
    result.cityId = std::stoi(input.substr(start, pos));

    start = pos + delimiter.size();
    pos = input.find(delimiter, start);
    result.cityName = input.substr(start, pos);

    return (result);
}
```

Comment: When I call the function in my readFile function using `std::vector<std::string> tokenStringVector = tokenizeString(line, "-");` I got an error that says `cannot convert from cityLoc to std::vector<std::string,std::allocator<std::string>>`

Comment: The return value is of type `struct cityLoc` now. This means, you cannot use a `vector` anymore, but change it to `cityLoc city = tokenizeString(...);`, of course.

Comment: I tried that but now it crashes the program instead with an `std::invalid_argument at memory location` error

Comment: Ok, and where does it throw that exception? Is this inside `tokenizeString()` or somewhere in `main()`?

Comment: I get a microsoft c++ runtime library debug error everytime I run the program after putting in `tokenizeString()`, however when I use the debugger it shows all the expected values inside `tokenizeString()`

Comment: When the values inside tokenizeString() are corrent, then it might be the usage of city after calling tokenizeString()